# How to use enumerate and slicing together

Tags: python-3.x, slice, enumerate

The following is the normal usage of enumerate for the case that i want to have every 10 items:

```
for index, value in enumerate(range(50)):
    if index % 10 == 0:
        print(index,value)
```

Output:

```
0 0
10 10
20 20
30 30
40 40
```

now imagine i want to have output as:

```
1 1
11 11
21 21
31 31
41 41
```

or

```
2 2
12 12
22 22
32 32
42 42
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are doing it this way but you can just subtract `n` from `index` in the test, e.g.:

```
In []:
n = 1
for index, value in enumerate(range(50)):
    if (index-n) % 10 == 0:
        print(index,value)

Out[]:
1 1
11 11
21 21
31 31
41 41
```

Just set `n=2` for your second case and if course `n=0` is the base case.

Alternatively, just start from `-n` in enumerate, which gives you the right values (but different index):

```
In []:
n = 1
for index, value in enumerate(range(50), -n):
    if index % 10 == 0:
        print(index,value)

Out[]:
0 1
10 11
20 21
30 31
40 41
```

But you really don't need to `enumerate` and `%` the index to get every 10th value, assuming you want to work on any iterable just use `itertools.islice()`, e.g.

```
In []:
import itertools as it
n = 0
for value in it.islice(range(50), n, None, 10):
    print(value)

Out[]:
0
10
20
30
40
```

Then just change the value of `n`, e.g.:

```
In []:
n = 1
for value in it.islice(range(50), n, None, 10):
    print(value)

Out[]:
1
11
21
31
41
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following function:

```
def somefunc(n):
    for i in list(range(50))[n::10]:
        yield i, i
```

Then call the function with the desired integer:

```
for i, j in somefunc(2):
     print(i, j)
```

should for example return

```
2, 2
12, 12
22, 22
...
```

if I am right.